# JavaScript Curly braces argument as function parameter

Tags: javascript, curly-braces

I am not very experienced with javascript and have a question relating to curly braces used around a function parameter, since its not a JSON structure.

I am learning nuclear js, and I found some code as example, but I don't understand it well - why is "product" is in braces?:

```
addToCart(product) {
    reactor.dispatch(ADD_TO_CART, { product })
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is an ES2015 (also called ES6) shorthand to create objects.

`{ product }` is equivalent to `{ product: product }`.

Basically, you end up with an object with a property called `"product"` that has the value of the `product` variable.

```js
const prop = "prop value";
const obj = { prop, anotherProp: "something else" }
console.log("obj: ", obj);
```

Have a look [at the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [here](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand.html) if you need a more detailed explanation.

It is a relatively new syntax so old browsers (e.g. IE) are likely to raise a syntax error, however it starts to be quite well supported amongst modern browsers. Have a look here for [the ES2015 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_shorthand_properties).

Answer (score 2):

This is ES6 shorthand syntax for defining object having same key as the variable name.

`{product}` is same as `{ product: product }`.

[**Property Shorthand**](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand)

[**MDN Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions)